# Internet not working on VM with Ubuntu Server 10.04.4 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, connection, vmware

I've received an VM to work on. It worked opening it but it doesn't connect automatically at the Internet, and I need the connection to update my revision througout svn.

Is there any setting to do on VMware 7 or from ubuntu command line to solve this?

```
ping: unknown host google.com // this is what I get when running ping
could not resolve hostname '...' // this is at svn up
```

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 172.16.90.2
domain localdomain
search localdomain
```

ifconfig

```
inet addr: 127.0.0.1
```

Meanwhile I've found the solution if anyone has this problem:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
- now, delete everything in this file past the initial comment
- save the file and close it
- then restart the vm and your network should work
```

Comment: it seems you miss configuration of DNS servers. post the output of "cat /etc/resolv.conf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no address other then `127.0.0.1` then you won't be able to go out to the net.

The `127.0.0.1` is a loopback interface connecting back to your own machine.  So you would need to go into the settings for your virtual machine and check the network configuration and also set an IP address for interface(s) other then `lo0`.